# Django form : Doesn't display any form errors

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting an issue with my Django `form validation`. I would like to display `form errors` and make all fields `required`. I don't know why my fields can accept blank while `blank` is not defined in my model file.

This is my model :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_('e-mail'), null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name=_('first name'), null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name=_('last name'), null=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, verbose_name=_('country'))
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('institution'), null=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_('creation date'), null=False)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_('modification date'), null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('customer')
        verbose_name_plural = _('customer')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email}"
```

This is my form :

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['country'].empty_label = _('Select a country')  
        self.fields['country'].queryset = self.fields['country'].queryset.order_by(
            'name')  
        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'country', 'institution']
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('name@example.com')}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First Name')}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Last Name')}),
            'institution': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Agency, company, academic or other affiliation')}),
        }
```

You can find here my view with Django CBV :

```
class HomeView(CreateView):
    """ Render the home page """

    template_name = 'app/index.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['document_list'] = Document.objects.all().order_by('publication__category__name')
        return super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        email = request.POST['email']
        country_id = request.POST['country']
        country = Country.objects.get(id=country_id)

        for checkbox in request.POST.getlist('DocumentChoice'):
            document = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox)
            token = self.gen_token(email, document.edqm_id)
            Download.objects.create(email=email, country=country, pub_id=checkbox, token=token,
                                    expiration_date=now + timedelta(minutes=10))

            if not form.is_valid():
                print('form invalid')
                continue

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And finally my template :

```
{% extends "publication/base_backend.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block main %}

  <form method="post" id="customerform" novalidate>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <h3>{% trans 'Your information' %}</h3>
      <hr>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    {{ form.email|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="alert alert-info col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" role="alert">
        <small>{%  trans "The fields below are optional if you have already requested a publication:" %}</small>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      {{ form.first_name|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}<br>
      {{ form.country|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
      {{ form.last_name|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}<br>
      {{ form.institution|as_crispy_field:"bootstrap" }}
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-12">
       <br />
       <br />
     </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{% trans 'Save' %}"/>
      <a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" class="btn btn-default">{% trans 'Cancel' %}</a>


 </form>
```

***Issues :***

According to required fields, I don't know why my form doesn't display missing values errors when I want to submit it.

I have to display fields as shown in my template because I have to make bootstrap design.

In order to display form errors, I have to write `{{form.email.errors}}` for example but nothing appears.

Thank you by advance

Comment: Because you've overridden `post` and always .

Comment: I should create another method and don't override `post` ?